# Need Help Converting Regex From VB.NET To C#

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I hired a coder to code me something in Regex. The issue was that he coded it in Visual Basic and I need it in C#.

I tried using a converter but it didnt fix the issue.

Mind helping me convert the following Regex to C#? The issues are with GetBetween and Strings Thanks:

```
string iamtwit = ss("http://www.mailinator.com" + GetBetween(GetBetween(iamtwit1, matches.ToString(), "</a>"), "<a href=", ">"));
```

and

```
MessageBox.Show(GetBetween(matches1.ToString(), "<a href=\"", Strings.Chr(34)));
```

Here is the original code:

```
Dim iamtwit As String = ss("http://www.mailinator.com" & GetBetween(GetBetween(iamtwit1, matches.ToString, "</a>"), "<a href=", ">"))


MsgBox(GetBetween(matches1.ToString, "<a href=""", Chr(34)))
```

The error messages I am getting are:

> The name 'GetBetween' does not exist in the current context
>
> The name 'Strings' does not exist in the current context

Comment: That is C#... notice the semicolons?  Please post the VB.NET Code so that we can see exactly what's going on.

Comment: But I am getting an error with the line: GetBetween

Comment: GetBetween is a function... probably also needs converted from the VB.NET Code

Comment: @DanAndrews - Why would it need converting? It must be in a referenced assembly in order to work.

Comment: @Oded, if it's in the class that he's trying to convert.  Ash is right too.

Comment: And that is not regex really, seems you need yet another developer?

Comment: @DanAndrews - **if**. I don't know if it is in the class, but seeing as it is C# that was posted (and there are no regular expressions in place), I am assuming it _is_ in a referenced assembly.

Comment: I bet function GetBetween does Regex - doh

Comment: Thats what the converter gave me. Heres the raw VB code: 
Dim iamtwit As String = ss("http://www.mailinator.com" & GetBetween(GetBetween(iamtwit1, matches.ToString, "</a>"), "<a href=", ">")) and

Comment: @Oded: If it was a reference assembly, he wouldn't get an error.

Comment: @user1017524: Can you PLEASE post the original VB.NET Code?

Comment: You really need to post the error details if you want anyone to understand what is going on, as well as the _actual_ code causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
        {
            int Start, End;
            if (strSource.Contains(Starting) && strSource.Contains(Ending))
            {
                Start = strSource.IndexOf(Starting, 0) + strStart.Length;
                End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
                return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Contains is just a wrapper around the IndexOf function. You should call directly IndexOf and check if the result is -1

Comment: I agree with not using `Contains`.  However, it's not for the (probably micro)optimization of only searching the string once, but rather that the current implementation throws when called as `getBetween("</a><a>test", "<a>", "</a>")`.  Also, you are using `Starting` and `Ending` without defining them.

Answer (score 2):

GetBetween is most likely the code from [this article](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/40934).

Converted to C#:

```
    public string GetBetween(string sSearch, string sStart, string sStop, int lSearch = 1)
    {
        string retVal = null;
        lSearch = (sSearch.IndexOf(sStart, lSearch - 1, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) + 1);
        if (lSearch > 0)
        {
            lSearch = lSearch + sStart.Length;
            int lTemp = 0;
            lTemp = (sSearch.IndexOf(sStop, lSearch - 1) + 1);
            if (lTemp > lSearch)
            {
                retVal = sSearch.Substring(lSearch - 1, lTemp - lSearch);
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted in C#, not VB.NET. It also does not contain any regular expressions.

Import the assembly and use the types directly, as you seem to be doing already. I am assuming you need the `GetBetween` method.

One of the points of .NET is that people can use different languages and interoperate with them.

Comment: How do I fix the Getbetween issue?

Comment: @user1017524 - You didn't actually explain what the issue _is_.